# I'm trying to store more than one spider's results into seperate tables in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, web-scraping, scrapy

Here is my pipelines.py. I have two spiders one called bristol.py and one bath.py. When I run 'scrapy crawl bristol' it automatically adds the results to my MySQL database tabled called 'Bristol'. I want to run 'srapy crawl bath' and to be able to store the results in the MySQL database under the table name 'Bath'. I've tried adding the exact same line of code for the 'Bristol' table but I receive an error. This is the code I've tried putting directly underneath the first self.cursor.execute

```
self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Bath(BathCountry, BathQualification) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}')""".format(item['BathCountry'], "".join([s.encode('utf8') for s in item['BathQualification']])))
```

When I try this I receive an error, is there a way of doing this? This is the error

```
 exceptions.KeyError: 'BathCountry'
```

Thank for your help in advance.

```
import sys
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
import hashlib
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class TestPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(
            user='user',
            passwd='password',
            db='db',
            host='host',
            charset='utf8',
            use_unicode=True
            )
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Bristol(BristolCountry, BristolQualification) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}')""".format(item['BristolCountry'], "".join([s.encode('utf8') for s in item['BristolQualification']])))
            self.conn.commit()
            return item

        except MySQLdb.Error as e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
```

Comment: Could you show your `Item` definition(s)? Are you using the same `Item` class for both spiders?

Comment: Hello, here they are, should they be seperate Item classes? How would I define this. 

from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class QualificationItem(Item):
    BristolQualification = Field()
    BristolCountry = Field()
    BathQualification = Field()
    BathCountry = Field()

Comment: I've changed it now to an if and elif statement between the 'self.cursor.execute(s)', it works but it skips some of the results, in the bath example it returns 41 lines when it should return 50+ (I can't remember the exact number) I can see it's missing some countries. Any advice?

Comment: make sure the item from the bath spider contains 'BathCountry'