# Spider not returning all results after changing my item pipelines to an if and elif statement

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

If you look  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994068/im-trying-to-store-more-than-one-spiders-results-into-seperate-tables-in-mysql?noredirect=1#comment35117321_22994068) I could not get two different spiders to automatically add the results to a mysql database. Now I've added an if and elif statement and they work but they miss out some results, previously there were 52 rows in the bath table, now there is only 41. Bristol used to have 154 now only 141. I cannot think why the results are not the same.

### Pipelines.py

```
import sys
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
import hashlib
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class TestPipeline(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(
        user='user',
        passwd='pwd',
        db='db',
        host='host',
        charset='utf8',
        use_unicode=True
        )
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    try:
        if 'BristolQualification' in item:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Bristol(BristolCountry, BristolQualification) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}')""".format(item['BristolCountry'], "".join([s.encode('utf8') for s in item['BristolQualification']])))
        elif 'BathQualification' in item:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Bath(BathCountry, BathQualification) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}')""".format(item['BathCountry'], "".join([s.encode('utf8') for s in item['BathQualification']])))
        self.conn.commit()
        return item

    except MySQLdb.Error as e:
        print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
```

### Items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class QualificationItem(Item):
BristolQualification = Field()
BristolCountry = Field()
BathQualification = Field()
BathCountry = Field()
```

### Bristol.py

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from project.items import QualificationItem
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from urlparse import urljoin

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0'

class recursiveSpider(BaseSpider):
name = 'bristol'
allowed_domains = ['bristol.ac.uk/']
start_urls = ['http://www.bristol.ac.uk/international/countries/']

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    xpath = '//*[@id="all-countries"]/li/ul/li/a/@href'
    a_of_the_link = '//*[@id="all-countries"]/li/ul/li/a/text()'
    for text, link in zip(hxs.select(a_of_the_link).extract(), hxs.select(xpath).extract()):
        yield Request(urljoin(response.url, link),
        meta={'a_of_the_link': text},
        headers={'User-Agent': USER_AGENT},
        callback=self.parse_linkpage,
        dont_filter=True)

def parse_linkpage(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = QualificationItem()
    xpath = """
            //h2[normalize-space(.)="Entry requirements for undergraduate courses"]
             /following-sibling::p[not(preceding-sibling::h2[normalize-space(.)!="Entry requirements for undergraduate courses"])]
            """
    item['BristolQualification'] = hxs.select(xpath).extract()[1:]
    item['BristolCountry'] = response.meta['a_of_the_link']
    return item
```

Comment: I think we're going to need your full spider code in order to test. :)

Comment: Just added one spider named bristol.py

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reproduce the issue when testing with Sqlite3 and the number of errors in the scrapy log corresponded to the missing entries. These errors were caused by unescaped single quotes in the `BristolQualification` item field (and presumably the Bath spider suffers from the same problem) causing havoc (such as `d'Etudes` in the snippet below):

> Candidates holding a Dipl\xf4me de Technicien Sup\xe9rieur / Sciences Appliqu\xe9es with suitable grades or those with the Dipl\xf4me d'Etudes Universitaires G\xe9n\xe9rales (DEUG) with good grades in suitable subjects will be considered for appropriate undergraduate courses.

I managed to get it working (at least with SQLite3) by breaking up the join and encoding of the qualification item field. The code below should work, but please note that it is untested with MySQL. If any errors occur, then check the scrapy log errors and let me know if there are any problems.

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    try:
        if 'BristolQualification' in item:
            qualification = ''.join(s for s in item['BristolQualification'])
            qualification.encode('utf8')
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Bristol(BristolCountry, BristolQualification) VALUES (?, ?)", (item['BristolCountry'], qualification))
        elif 'BathQualification' in item:
            qualification = ''.join(s for s in item['BathQualification'])
            qualification.encode('utf8')
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Bath(BathCountry, BathQualification) VALUES (?, ?)", (item['BathCountry'], qualification))
        self.conn.commit()
        return item

    except MySQLdb.Error as e:
        print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your help, here is the error I'm receiving.
    qualification = ''.join(s for s in item['BristolQualification'])
                ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block. With the ^ pointing towards the last N in qualification.

Comment: So that's a copy/paste error rather than a coding error.

Try deleting the space between the end of `if 'BristolQualification' in item:` and the next line, then hitting enter and then using the space bar until the line is in the correct place.

Are you able to view spaces and tabs in your text editor or IDE? That should give you an idea if there are tabs or spaces in the wrong place.

Comment: Is this working now or are you still getting indentation errors?

Comment: Hello I'm only now getting on the computer. I did what you said, (I should have know that myself haha) but now I get an error.
    query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
exceptions.TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: What version of Python are you using btw?

Comment: I'm running python 2.7

Comment: I'm downloading mySQL to see if I can repro your error. Could you post your schema code via Gist or a similar site please? https://gist.github.com/

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want me to show you, do you have a chat so we can talk more freely?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50703/discussion-between-talvalin-and-dyl10)

Comment: Hey mate, any luck? I'm still in chat, if not I'll try asking again, thanks!