# Web spider not returning all results

Tags: python, mysql, sql, scrapy

If you look  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994068/im-trying-to-store-more-than-one-spiders-results-into-seperate-tables-in-mysql?noredirect=1#comment35117321_22994068) I could not get two different spiders to automatically add the results to a mysql database. Now I've added an if and elif statement and they work but they miss out some results, previously there were 52 rows in the bath table, now there is only 41. Bristol used to have 154 now only 141. I cannot think why the results are not the same.

### Pipelines.py

```
import sys
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
import hashlib
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class TestPipeline(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(
        user='user',
        passwd='pwd',
        db='db',
        host='host',
        charset='utf8',
        use_unicode=True
        )
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    try:
        if 'BristolQualification' in item:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Bristol(BristolCountry, BristolQualification) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}')""".format(item['BristolCountry'], "".join([s.encode('utf8') for s in item['BristolQualification']])))
        elif 'BathQualification' in item:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Bath(BathCountry, BathQualification) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}')""".format(item['BathCountry'], "".join([s.encode('utf8') for s in item['BathQualification']])))
        self.conn.commit()
        return item

    except MySQLdb.Error as e:
        print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
```

### Items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class QualificationItem(Item):
BristolQualification = Field()
BristolCountry = Field()
BathQualification = Field()
BathCountry = Field()
```

### Bristol.py

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from project.items import QualificationItem
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from urlparse import urljoin

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0'

class recursiveSpider(BaseSpider):
name = 'bristol'
allowed_domains = ['bristol.ac.uk/']
start_urls = ['http://www.bristol.ac.uk/international/countries/']

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    xpath = '//*[@id="all-countries"]/li/ul/li/a/@href'
    a_of_the_link = '//*[@id="all-countries"]/li/ul/li/a/text()'
    for text, link in zip(hxs.select(a_of_the_link).extract(), hxs.select(xpath).extract()):
        yield Request(urljoin(response.url, link),
        meta={'a_of_the_link': text},
        headers={'User-Agent': USER_AGENT},
        callback=self.parse_linkpage,
        dont_filter=True)

def parse_linkpage(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = QualificationItem()
    xpath = """
            //h2[normalize-space(.)="Entry requirements for undergraduate courses"]
             /following-sibling::p[not(preceding-sibling::h2[normalize-space(.)!="Entry requirements for undergraduate courses"])]
            """
    item['BristolQualification'] = hxs.select(xpath).extract()[1:]
    item['BristolCountry'] = response.meta['a_of_the_link']
    return item
```

If you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045582/spider-not-returning-all-results-after-changing-my-item-pipelines-to-an-if-and-e/23050395?noredirect=1#comment35287235_23050395) an user did try to fix the problem but was unsuccessful an I haven't heard from him since.

> 'These errors were caused by unescaped single quotes in the BristolQualification item field (and presumably the Bath spider suffers from the same problem) causing havoc (such as d'Etudes in the snippet below):'

This is what he thought the problem was.

Can anyone see where the problem is at?